# How to extract HH:MM from a pandas datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I just want to extract from my `df` HH:MM. How do I do it?

Here's a description of the column in the `df`:

```
count                     810
unique                    691
top       2018-07-25 11:14:00
freq                        5
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

The string value includes a full time stamp. The goal is to parse each row's `HH:MM` into another df, and to loop back over and extract just the `%Y-%m-%d` into another df.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assume the df looks like

```
print(df)

             date_col
0 2018-07-25 11:14:00
1 2018-08-26 11:15:00
2 2018-07-29 11:17:00
#convert from string to datetime
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col']) 

#to get date only
print(df['date_col'].dt.date)
0    2018-07-25
1    2018-08-26
2    2018-07-29

#to get time:
print(df['date_col'].dt.time)

0    11:14:00
1    11:15:00
2    11:17:00
#to get hour and minute
print(df['date_col'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
0    11:14
1    11:15
2    11:17
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert to datetime:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

Then you can do:

```
df2['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.strptime('%H:%M')
df3['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: What assumption are you making here? Where does the `dt` come from? This results in an `AttributeError` for me. If I do `from datetime import datetime as dt` this results in `DatetimeProperties object has no attribute strptime`.

Comment: Can't update my comment, so, understand the `dt` now - it's the accessor. `strftime` is only available though, not `strptime`

Answer (score 0):

General solution (not pandas based)

```
import time
top = '2018-07-25 11:14:00'
time_struct = time.strptime(top, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
short_top = time.strftime('%H:%M', time_struct)
print(short_top)
```

Output

```
11:14
```